# show error when i am trying to build the ios using xamarin forms from window

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using xamarin forms for my project using visual studio 2022 on window. When I am trying to take IPA file from the project with the Remote Device as target platform, i got the following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to codesign '/Users/dev1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CP.mypro.App.iOS/453d74550fbc3f6c6544e031e2aae6db77e393d9ad1e4d70c67da4c28cd90e8b/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/CPMYPROAppiOS.app': /Users/dev1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CP.MYPRO.App.iOS/453d74550fbc3f6c6544e031e2aae6db77e393d9ad1e4d70c67da4c28cd90e8b/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/CPMYPROAppiOS.app: cannot find code object on disk    CP.MYPRO.App.iOS            
Error       /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
/Users/dev1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CP.MYPRO
.App.iOS/453d74550fbc3f6c6544e031e2aae6db77e393d9ad1e4d70c67da4c28cd90e8b/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/CPMYPROAppiOS.app: cannot find code object on disk  CP.MYPRO.App.iOS
```

Provisioning profile correctly executed. But I got the error.

Please refer the attachments for properties.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it happen when deploying on simulator? Does it happen for debug mode?

Comment: No, it happens on Ad-Hoc and Release Mode also. I am deploying on iphone X device

Comment: Do you mean in debug mode it worked well? Have you checked this thread : [.iOS.app: cannot find code object on disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1098258/usr-bin-codesign-ios-app-cannot-find-code-object-o)?

Comment: Sorry, Debug mode is working "Local Devices" only, not an "Remote Devices"

Comment: Have you included the iphoneX  in the provisioning file?

Comment: Hi, you could try creating an easy project with initial template to see if it could be correctly deployed.